# Exception display to the right of Command Line for PyQt/PySide callbacks/slots in Autodesk Maya

Tags: exception, pyqt, pyside, maya

**Updated: to make it much clearer.**

In the following code snippets, making use of Maya widgets through `pymel`, there is an error highlight on the right of Command Line.

```
import pymel.core as pm

def raiseError():
    pm.select("ooxx") # ooxx doesn't exist
    print "Something after the exception."

class pymelWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainWin = pm.window("test")
        with self.mainWin:
            mainForm = pm.formLayout()
            with mainForm:
                btn = pm.button(label='show error',command=pm.Callback(raiseError))
            mainForm.redistribute()

    def show(self):
        self.mainWin.show()

win = pymelWindow()
win.show()
```

Here attached is an snapshot of Maya 2011 (the same issue in Maya2014) with an error highlight (**in red**).

[image: Maya with error highlight to the right of Command Line.]

and here is the Stack Trace:

```
# Error: Maya Node does not exist: u'ooxx'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "/usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymel/internal/factories.py", line 778, in callback
#     res = origCallback( *newargs )
#   File "/usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymel/internal/factories.py", line 701, in __call__
#     return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
#   File "/dept/rdworks/drake/Desktop/pyqt_issues/testPyQtSpitError.py", line 119, in raiseError
#     pm.select("ooxx")
#   File "/usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymel/core/general.py", line 151, in select
#     raise TypeError, msg
# MayaNodeError: Maya Node does not exist: u'ooxx' #
```

However, when I switch to use PyQt/PySide for widgets with the following code snippets, there is no any visible *error highlight to the right of Command Line*! Does anyone know how to make PyQt/PySide version have the same GUI behaviours?

```
import pymel.core as pm
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def raiseError():
    pm.select("ooxx") # ooxx doesn't exist
    print "Something after the exception."

class pyQtWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        # init our ui using the MayaWindow as parent
        super(pyQtWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.centralLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.centralLayout)

        self.errorBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('show error')
        self.errorBtn.clicked.connect(raiseError)
        self.centralLayout.addWidget(self.errorBtn)

win = pyQtWindow()
win.show()
```

[image: Maya without error highlight to the right of Command Line!]

```
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "/usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymel/internal/factories.py", line 701, in __call__
#     return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
#   File "/dept/rdworks/drake/Desktop/pyqt_issues/testPyQtSpitError.py", line 119, in raiseError
#     pm.select("ooxx")
#   File "/usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymel/core/general.py", line 151, in select
#     raise TypeError, msg
# pymel.core.general.MayaNodeError: Maya Node does not exist: u'ooxx'
```

Comment: By *error highlight in line display* you the output window in Maya's script editor?

Comment: Is `Something after the exception.` printed, when the PyQt/PySide code block is used?

Comment: @BleedingFingers I'm sure there is nothing printed after the exception. The testing is just that simple in question without any further stuff.

Comment: @BleedingFingers I also put a snapshot to help make question clearer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you switched on the `Show Stack Trace` option in the script editor? *Edit->Show Stack Trace*

Comment: @BleedingFingers Sure and the same situation.

Comment: Just update the description and images to make it much clearer.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace that you get from both the codes in text forms. This would greatly help future user in finding the question.

Comment: If I am not wrong you are using Maya 2011 instead of 2014 which you mention.

Comment: I am developing under Maya2014.

Comment: Your traceback says `/usr/bin/maya2011-x64/...` unless you've install Maya2014 in that directory, that means you've tested the code on Maya2011.

Comment: Well, I have tested on both Maya2011/2014, and I just provided screenshots in Maya2011. That's not the point.

Comment: Culprit's PyQt it's actually catching, culling and printing the error. That's why no *red* bar. Somehow this action needs to be stopped. I consider it a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PyQt/PySide then the default behavior upon getting an exception wont display the error in red. I have no idea *why* nor do I know of any switch which does that.

In order the achieve that you'd have to change the `raiseError` function to something like this:

```
def raiseError():
    import maya.OpenMaya as om
    import traceback as tb
    import sys
    try:
        pm.select("ooxx") # ooxx doesn't exist
    except Exception as exc:
        msg = "".join(tb.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())) # or any custom msg
        om.MGlobal.displayError(msg)
    finally:
        print "Something after the exception."
```

This way you'll get the red error display.

Comment: I believe that `Callback` is much more responsible for 1) deferred function evaluation with baked arguments and 2) one undo entry.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's something internal which requires some heavy introspection. No doubt this thing has left me in a conundrum.